# Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that for any two real numbers $x$ and $y$

Tags: continuity

> Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that for any two real numbers $x$ and $y$,
> $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq 7{|x-y|}^{201}$
> then,
>
> (A) $f(101) =f(202) +8$
>
> (B) $f(101) = f(201) +1$
>
> (C) $f(101) = f(200) + 2$
>
> (D) None of the above.
> [Source ISI UGA 2017](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2017.pdf)

I have no idea how to solve questions like this, please help me. Or give me some hint.

Comment: You construct a counterexample

Comment: @edm,what will be it??

Comment: Suppose $f$ is the zero function (or any constant function).

Comment: Then only the inequality holds, not the answer

Comment: @BaponDas not the answer? Is "None of the above" not an answer?

Comment: $|f(x+h) - f(x)| < 7 h^{201} \implies |f'(x)|  = \lim_\limits {h\to 0} \frac {|f(x+h) - f(x)|}{|h|} \le 7h^{200} \implies f'(x) = 0$

Comment: The last choice (none of the above) holds.

Comment: But you have to prove that $f$ _must_ be constant.

Comment: Existence of the derivative is what you _prove_, simultaneously showing that it must be zero everywhere.

Comment: @mathmore but it is differentiable... I have proven that the derivative exists.

Comment: @DougM how can you say that f'(x) =0,from the previous line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by $\lvert\,x-y\,\rvert$ and let $y$ approach $x$ to see that $f'(x)=0$ for every $x$ and thus $f$ is a constant function so (D) is the answer. As Sherlock said, the easiest way to hide something is to put it in plain sight.